# Characters Method not Capturing all Data for Element - SAX Parser - Java

Tags: java, android, xml, xml-parsing, sax

I am parsing an XML document using the SAX parser. I am using the characters method to capture the data provided between two element tags, accounting for the fact that the data will be provided in chunks :

```
StringBuilder currentText = new StringBuilder();

...

public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length) {
        if (currentText!=null) {
            for (int i=start; i<start+length; i++) {
                currentText.append(ch[i]);
            }
```

Then in the endElement method I am using :

```
public void endElement(String namespaceURI, String localName, String qName) throws SAXException {
        System.out.println("Current Text is " + currentText.toString());
        currentText.setLength(0);
```

}

The problem is that when I look in the log, currentText is not capturing the entire contents of some of the larger data fields in the XML.

Does anyone know why this could be happening ?

Thank you.

Comment: Hi UNNI. One element I'm looking at contains 15516 items, each item being a float of 6 digits.

Comment: are digits separated by commas?

Comment: No - they are separated by spaces.

Comment: Uhm, **don't** rely on logcat to print 15516 6-digit floats for you to analyze.. have you tried writing `currentText` to a file on the SDCARD, pulling it over to your computer and going through it there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, there's always the possibility that currentText==null - you can eliminate that possibility, we can't.

Note that your character loop to do the append is horribly inefficient: you can use

public StringBuilder append(char str[], int offset, int len)

You might be missing some whitespace reported to the ignorableWhitespace callback, but I guess if it was only whitespace missing, you would have told us.

Sorry, can't suggest any more. Follow my grandmother's motto: if you're looking for something and can't find it, that means you are looking in the wrong place; so look somewhere else.

Comment: Thanks Michael - I like that motto and turns out it was right. I've wasted hours before discovering that logcat TRUNCATES STRINGS. (Deep breaths). Everything was actually working fine.